# (LocalDB) Erro pós comando Update-Database -> "Cannot attach the file ...."

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, migrations

estou tentando usar o Sql Serve LocalDB em uma aplicação com o Entity Framework e Migrations, mas quando dou o comando Update-Database, ocorre o seguinte erro:

> Cannot attach the file
>   'C:\Diretorios\9-ProjetosMVS\TesteDeDB\TesteDeDB\bin\Debug\TesteDB.mdf'
>   as database 'TesteDB'.

Já tentei:

> sqllocaldb.exe stop MSSqlLocalDb
>
> sqllocaldb.exe delete MSSqlLocalDb

E não resolveu... :/

**Este é o meu Contexto:**

```
using System.Data.Entity;
using TesteDeDB.Entidades;

namespace TesteDeDB.Contexto
{
    class ClasseContexto : DbContext
    {
        public ClasseContexto()
            : base("name=Model1")
        {
        }

        public DbSet<Cliente> clientes { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

**Esta é a classe configuration do Migrations:**

```
namespace TesteDeDB.Migrations
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;
    using System.Linq;

    internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Contexto.ClasseContexto>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(Contexto.ClasseContexto context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data.
        }
    }
}
```

**E esta é a entidade que estou tentando criar no BD:**

```
namespace TesteDeDB.Entidades
{
    public class Cliente
    {
        public int clienteID { get; set; }
        public string nome { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**E esta é minha connection String:**

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\TesteDB.mdf;initial catalog=TesteDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Conectou no `sql-server`, usando por exemplo o *Management Studio* e verificou se a base de dados "TesteDB" está atachada e online?

Comment: Sim, ela esta anexada e online! Minha versão é a 2014

Comment: E no seu programa, como está a *string de conexão*?

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="Model1" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb;attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\TesteDB.mdf;initial catalog=TesteDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema está na sua string de conexão. Essa parte:

`attachdbfilename=|DataDirectory|\TesteDB.mdf` diz ao banco que ele **deve** atachar o arquivo "TesteDB.mdf" que está no "DataDirectory".

Se o banco já existe e está atachado, precisa remover essa parte da string de conexão:

```
<add name="Model1" connectionString="data source=(LocalDb)\MSSQLLocalDb;initial catalog=TesteDB;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Além disso, você pode ter de colocar a versão do sql se não funcionar, assim:
`Server=(localdb)\\v12.0;`.  Isso porque você está usando a versão 2014, para a versão 2012 é "V11.0", e assim por diante: [instâncias SQL Server](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/sql-server/install/file-locations-for-default-and-named-instances-of-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: Deu certo! Como o banco Já existe bastou mudar a connection string assim como você disse :-D muito obrigado!